# Can't seem to get SQUARE oauth2 authorize to load up

Tags: oauth-2.0, square-connect, square

When i sent a merchant to the authorization url

https://squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=sq0idp-Lno1QXpjx8Z2Avemg3orUg&response_type=code&scope=MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ%20PAYMENTS_WRITE%20ORDERS_WRITE%20ITEMS_READ

I get the following error.

> An error occurred Client requires a Redirect URL to use OAuth

I most certainly have a redirect url set.

Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Answer, square is trash.

It was not saving the Redirect URL, I enter it, press save, get the green bar that says its saved... think its saved, my mistake.

Log out, then log back in, empty field...

Had to do it SIX times before it actually saved..